# Eclipse: Enable Java error markers in standalone SourceViewer widget

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, jface, markers

So I am working with Eclipse, and am trying to enable Java error highlighting inside of a standalone SourceViewer. I have done quite a bit of searching the web, but nothing seems to come up. I have looked into dealing with Annotations, Markers, etc... Everything that comes up seems to be for implementing custom methods.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Text

has helped a bit, but seems to be not exactly what I want.

The SourceViewer is going to be a basic Java editor, so it can be assumed that everything will be java code. I would just like the red squiggly lines to appear under syntax errors, maybe also have the red boxes on a ruler on the side. There should be a default easy way to enable this, but I cannot find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is doable, but it can be a bit of work.  What makes it difficult is that a standalone `SourceViewer` widget doesn't support the `IDocumentProvider` interface that does a lot of the work so you have to do all of that yourself.

I found this post helpful as far as adding the red squiggly lines is concerned:
http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t30082.html

For the squiggly lines you want to set up an `AnnotationPainter`.

If you want the red boxes on a ruler, use the SourceViewer constructor that accepts an `IOverviewRuler`.  There's a standard OverviewRuler that should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for thehiatus.

The annotation stuff is really complicated. I tried to convert an editor to a `IViewPart` some time back... It took at long time to get it to work... well almost... almost, but quite like the real thing :-) (A bit like Swing and Microsoft Vista).

Also have a look at `TextEditor` and the the methods `createAnnotationAccess()` and `configureSourceViewerDecorationSupport(...)`.